# Closed forms for two times series similar to geometric series, but with additional power

Tags: summation, approximation, closed-form, time-series, geometric-series

Does anyone know a close form solutions to any of the following time series? 
(approximate upper bounds might as well work).

$$
\sum_{k=1}^T \frac{1}{2^{k^2}} 
$$
or 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^T k \frac{1}{2^{k^2}} 
$$

Comment: BTW, I am not sure if the title is good. If you think I can make it better suggest me a modification.

Answer (score 0):

The first sum converges really fast as $T \to \infty$. For $T=10$ there are $35$ correct decimal digits. As $T \to \infty$ the first sum is related to [Jacobi theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html), and there is a closed-form solution in term of $\vartheta_3$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\vartheta_3\left(0,\tfrac12\right)-\frac{1}{2} \approx 0.56446841360593857933472927427247566\dots
$$
The closed-form is trivial from the definition of $\vartheta_3$ function. This value is a good upper bound of the partial sums for any finite $T$.

I didn't find similar closed-form solution to the second sum. The numerical value of the sum as $T \to \infty$ is the following:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^{k^2}} \approx 0.6309205592551858647783240039079433700921514299217879868\dots
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I am interested in is the growth rate of the series with respect to the upper bound of the summation, which is $T$.